# Is it possible to programatically change an msi's database on Linux

Tags: linux, windows-installer, orca, wsh

I know you can change it using cscript.exe on Windows. Is there a Linux program providing cscript-like functionality? Or is there some other way I can change the database in Linux?

Comment: MSI is supposedly the Microsoft Installer, a very Windows-specific beast. What are you even doing with that on Linux?

Comment: @Henning my guess is some sort of web service or site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CScript is just the script execution engine; it knows nothing about MSI directly. Check out Wine; it implements some/most of msi.dll, so as long as functions like MsiDatabaseOpenView and MsiViewExecute are correctly implemented, you should be able to use it to modify an .msi package.

Comment: Ugh. Yeah this is probably the way to do it. I think I'm going to end up running a Windows box instead of mucking around in a bunch of C libraries.

Comment: I ported Wine's code to a standalone library that can run on Linux - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13748696/111698 for more details.  Help is welcome, the source code is also on github at github.com/bonzini/msitools.git