# Read Windows Installer (MSI file) attributes from PHP

Tags: php, windows-installer

I have a Windows MSI file, that I need to programmatically read the version number from. The only place I can see this version is within the **Subject** of the file details:

[image: MSI file]

If I somehow can read the entire content of **Subject** this would be fine but is there any way to get this from PHP? The PHP is running in an IIS web server, if this helps ;-)

`stat` is of no help for this.

I considered doing a checksum of the file, and can do that, but I really need the real version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I am unable to find a native PHP solution for this, so I have temporarily solved this by calling a Powershell script as it seems easier to do in there.

I am now having this PHP code:
`$version = exec("powershell.exe -file GetMsiVersion.ps1 MyFile.msi);`

With my above picture then `$version` will contain `1.5.9`, so I will not even require to interpret the data from **Subject**.

The `GetMsiVersion.ps1` Powershell script has this code:

```
function Get-Property ($Object, $PropertyName, [object[]]$ArgumentList) {
    return $Object.GetType().InvokeMember($PropertyName, 'Public, Instance, GetProperty', $null, $Object, $ArgumentList)
}

function Invoke-Method ($Object, $MethodName, $ArgumentList) {
    return $Object.GetType().InvokeMember($MethodName, 'Public, Instance, InvokeMethod', $null, $Object, $ArgumentList)
}

$Path = $args[0]
$msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly = 0
$Installer = New-Object -ComObject WindowsInstaller.Installer
$Database = Invoke-Method $Installer OpenDatabase  @($Path, $msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly)
$View = Invoke-Method $Database OpenView  @("SELECT Value FROM Property WHERE Property='ProductVersion'")
Invoke-Method $View Execute
$Record = Invoke-Method $View Fetch
if ($Record) {
    Write-Output (Get-Property $Record StringData 1)
}

Invoke-Method $View Close @()
```

I will accept this as the best solution here-and-now but, I hope this can be archieved natively from PHP as I see this as a better and more clean solution - and by then I will accept that as the best answer (or at least *unaccept* my own temporary solution).

Doing an `exec` is a little evil ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Two things first:

1. I have never accessed COM from PHP, but below  are some VBScript samples of getting information from MSI files by using [MSI API - COM automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-reference). [There are also Win32 functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15322534/129130).
2. That field you refer to is not a version field, but a text field from the MSI's "Summary Stream" - a special part of the MSI file with "meta information" of various kinds. [Summary Information Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/summary-information-stream) (the full name).

Here is how you can get the REAL version of an MSI file. This is stored in the property **`"ProductVersion"`** in the MSI file. There are at least two different ways to retrieve it - by opening the MSI file as a session or just access the property table via SQL query:

***Access version via Session object:***

```vb
Const msiUILevelNone = 2
Dim installer : Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
installer.UILevel = msiUILevelNone

Set s = installer.OpenPackage("C:\MySetup.msi",1)

MsgBox CStr(s.ProductProperty("ProductVersion"))
```

***Accessing version via SQL agains MSI database (property table):***

```vb
Dim installer : Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")

' Open MSI database in read-only mode (0)
Set db = installer.OpenDatabase("C:\MySetup.msi", 0)
Set view = db.OpenView("SELECT `Value` FROM `Property` WHERE `Property`='ProductVersion'")
view.Execute

Set record = view.Fetch

MsgBox CStr(record.StringData(1))
```

Then there is the issue of accessing the SummaryStream - which is what you are really asking by the looks of it - here is a simple smoke test with some hints as to what properties you can retrieve - be careful with the summary stream - corruption is possible in various ways (I don't recall the details, but it should be safe to access read-only):

```vb
Dim installer : Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")

' Open MSI database in read-only mode (0)
Set db = installer.OpenDatabase("C:\MySetup.msi", 0)
MsgBox CStr(db.SummaryInformation.Property(3))

' 1 = "Codepage"
' 2 = "Title"
' 3 = "Subject"
' 4 = "Author"
' 5 = "Keywords"
' 6 = "Comments"
' 7 = "Template"
' 8 = "LastAuthor"
' 9 = "Revision"
' 11 = "Printed"
' 12 = "Created"
' 13 = "Saved"
' 14 = "Pages"
' 15 = "Words"
' 16 = "Characters"
' 18 = "Application"
' 19 = "Security"
```

---

***Links:***

- [Modify an MSI using MSI SQL VBScript WiRunSQL.vbs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51103086/129130)
- [List tables in MSI file using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58349808/129130)

Comment: Thanks for the details but I am sorry to say, that it does not bring me any closer to a native PHP solution as I cannot convert your VBScript suggesting to PHP ;-)